# operator<< overload for smart pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I would like to overload the operator<< to allow it to work with `shared_ptr`.

```
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    virtual foo& operator<<(const T& e) = 0;
};

foo<int> f1;
f1 << 1;

std::shared_ptr<foo<int>> f2(new foo<int>());
f2 << 1;
```

My first try is the following, but the problem is that it with also enable the behavior for any class.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
const std::shared_ptr<T>& operator<<(const std::shared_ptr<T>& o, const U& e)
{
    *o << e;
    return o;
}
```

My second try is the following:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
const std::shared_ptr<foo<T>>& operator<<(const std::shared_ptr<foo<T>>& o, const U& e)
{
    *o << e;
    return o;
}
```

The problem with this solution is not work for types inheriting foo since `T` cannot be automatically deduced.

So I could skip `U` and use `T` instead, in which case T will be deduced from the second argument and the argument for `o` can be converted into `foo<T>`.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
const std::shared_ptr<foo<T>>& operator<<(const std::shared_ptr<foo<T>>& o, const T& e)
{
    *o << e;
    return o;
}
```

But then the following will not work:

```
struct c    
{    
};

struct a
{
    a();
    a(c); // implicit conversion
};

struct b
{
    operator a(); // implicit conversion
};

auto f = std::make_shared<foo<a>>();
f << c; // doesn't work.
f << b; // doesn't work.
```

Any ideas on how make a working solution?

Comment: What do you want this overload to do?  I'm not sure it's a good idea...

Comment: Instead of writing `*f << b`, I want to be able to write `f << b`, independent of whether f is a value type or smart pointer.

Comment: That's the bit that doesn't sound like a good idea...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Care to expand on why?

Comment: @ronag: It obscures what happens. You smear the distinction between a pointer and its pointee. These are two different objects, and a `*` is a small price to pay to keep the distinction.

Comment: Right, I can buy that. I'll leave this question as an exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options, see the second live at **https://ideone.com/26nqr**

Given

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> struct foo {
    virtual foo& operator<<(const T& e) const { std::cout << "check foo\n"; }
};

//////
// derived instances

struct derived : foo<int> {
    virtual derived& operator<<(const int& e) const { std::cout << "check derived\n"; }
};

template<typename T> struct genericDerived : foo<T> {
    virtual derived& operator<<(const T& e) const { std::cout << "check genericDerived\n"; }
};
```

### Simple: template template arguments

```
template<typename T, typename U, template <typename> class X>
const std::shared_ptr<X<T>>& operator<<(const std::shared_ptr<X<T>>& o, const U& e)
{
    *o << e;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = make_shared<foo<int>>();
    f << 1;

    auto d = make_shared<derived>();
    d << 2; // compile error

    auto g = make_shared<genericDerived<int>>();
    g << 3; // SUCCESS!
}
```

### Completer: SFINAE

The above doesn't catch derived classes (case 2). To do that, I'd resort to

```
#include <type_traits>
namespace detail
{
    template<typename Foo, typename T>
        const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& dispatch_lshift(
                  const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& o, const T& e, 
                  const std::true_type& enabler)
        {
            *o << e;
            return o;
        }
}

template<typename Foo, typename T>
    const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& operator<<(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>& o, const T& e)
{
    return detail::dispatch_lshift(o, e, std::is_convertible<Foo*, foo<T>* >());
}

int main()
{
    auto f = make_shared<foo<int>>();
    f << 1;

    auto d = make_shared<derived>();
    d << 2;

    auto g = make_shared<genericDerived<int>>();
    g << 3;

    auto x = make_shared<int>();
    // x << 4; // correctly FAILS to compile    
}
```

Comment: It works because of (1) template template arguments, (2) [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) for the more complicated case

Comment: Yea, the template template argument bit is a bit tricky. Need to find my Moden C++ Design book again.

Comment: Somehow nobody noticed my earlier SFINAE version was broken (accepted any `shared_ptr<>`, because a _pointer_ to an incomplete type is not a problem). I have posted a better approach now...

Answer (score 1):

May be you're putting yourself in a *bad arena*, of making C++ to look like Java.

C++ pointers, values, and references are different types, and have different semantics and operations. It is not in general a good idea to mix them up into a same syntax. Pointers are not their values: they can point to types other than the one they refer (typical, in case of inheritance). So it is in general better to let pointer dereference to remain explicit.

Neverless, saving to a stream a "pointer value" (not "pointe**d** value") has no interest, since that value (a memory address) will be meaningless on stream reading.

If you properly want to "save what is pointed", when saving a pointer you should save something tells "what type of object you're saving", an then save the object polymorphically, (through a call to a virtual function) o that also the derived data are saved. Meanwhile, you also have to track circular references, in order not to save a same object multiple times (and loading it back as distinct objects), so an "identity" is also required.

To load the object back, you should first read the metadata you saved to describe the type, and based on that, create a corresponding object, then reassign its members to the data loaded on extraction. (Or if just an identity was saved, point the pointer to the already recreated corresponding object).

All that stuffs goes under the name of *serialization*. There are many solution around, you should probably Google for that key.

Comment: I don't want to save what is "pointed", I want to "send" #to# what is "pointed". This question does not have anything to do with serializations.

Comment: @ronag It has: if you want to "send", someone has to "receive". And to "receive" you must be able to reconstruct. And you cannot reconstruct if some information are missing.
 

Saving is just a particular case where "sending" and "receiving" happen in different time.

Comment: There is no serialization going on here, just simple method invocation.

Comment: @ronad: I don't insist. But you will be back here in a couple of weeks!

Comment: Likewise. In the meantime I suggest you take a look at sehe's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use your first solution with `enable_if` (I'm using C++03 namespaces):

```
template <typename T>
class is_funky : public boost::false_type {};

template <typename S>
class is_funky< Foo<S> > : public boost::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename U>
typename boost::enable_if< is_funky<T>, const boost::shared_ptr<T>& >::type 
operator<<(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& o, const U& e)
{
    *o << e;
    return o;
}
```

You might want to find a more appropriate name than `is_funky` in production code, but that depends on context.